# Select top 5 from a merged list (MVC)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two lists that have been merged.  After a order by linq statement, I would like to select the top 5 from that complete list.  I was thinking about using the linq statement to pick the top 5 from the list.

```
var ListSort = from list in NewList
orderby list.EntryDate
select list;//Tried to select the top 5 from here
```

Any other suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are going to use Linq, then use the [Take statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx)

```
   myList.Take(5)
```